# Why is my responsive html/css not working with mobile phone?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I've created a [test site](https://test.chozan.co/). I've used media queries in css but when I load the page on mobile, I don't see the mobile version and when I re-size the browser the site is responsive. I've read at multiple places to not to use `*-device-width`. So, what am I missing? What could be the resolution?

Comment: Add [`viewport meta tag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) in `head`

Comment: Check out the [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. I used javascript to override meta tag and it was causing issue in proper responsiveness. Fixed javascript.

Answer (score 6):

Add this to the head of your website:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This will set the width of your page to follow the screen width of your device.

Comment: what you've got is a set width on yours. So when you scale it down to mobile, its looking at that set width. Replace your current viewport with mine above and it works.

Comment: huh.. make sense.. I guess,, there was javascript which was messing/overwriting my settings.. thanks..